# NYTimes API, R - Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I'm new to the NYT API, and I seem to be running into some rate-liming error although I'm not anywhere near the 10,000 calls a day limit. Actually, I'm pausing two different times per query iteration just to be safe so that I should be averaging less than a query per second (API's max is 10 queries per second), so I thought my API calls should be super safe from a rules standpoint. But  my API calls keep failing every 20 calls or so to give me this:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Here's my code in case it matters:

```
getData <- function(url){
  raw.data <- readLines(url) 
  rd  <- fromJSON(raw.data)
  Sys.sleep(.2)
  rd[[1]]$meta$hits
}


for(i in 1:length(target_urls_years))
{
  print(i)
  z = target_urls_years[[i]]
  print(z)
  holder <- NULL
  for (j in z){
    dat = getData(j)
    holder <- rbind(holder,dat)
    Sys.sleep(.5)

  }
  print(holder)
  total_holder[[i]]= holder
}
```

I have not been able to make the loop run through - I had to break it up into segments and run a few at a time. Any ideas what might be causing this? Also what can I do in R so that the loop rights itself in this case and so I don't have to manually restart it?

Comment: Any warning after the Error? I was testing the API and received this error some times before creating a valid URL. Any chance sometimes the URL is not correct?

Comment: @Molx no warnings. Also I am trying again today, and it breaks at a different point in the loop each time. When I manually access the API url that caused the loop to break, it's fine on the API end as well.

Comment: @Molx I'm pretty sure it's something to do with their API - I have no dialed it down to wait 10 seconds between calls, and there haven't been any drops.

Comment: Ugh, also having the same problem in 2019. Not sure what's happening.